# Notifications.Builder in API 10

Tags: android, notifications

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setTicker(notificationMessage)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentTitle(newNotificationsCount + " New Notifications")
    .setContentText(notificationMessage);

Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
nm.notify(R.string.app_name, notification);
```

This gives error:

**Call requires API level 11 (current min is 10): android.app.Notification$Builder#setContentIntent**

I downloaded **android.support.v4.jar** added it to libs folder in the same directory as **src** and **res** etc.

right click on this jar from the project explorer and add to build path.

my application has a **min api = 10** and **target api = 15**

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The support class for Notification seems to have a different name, [`NotificationCompat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html). For your API 10 code you'll need to use:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
```

And change your import statement to:

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder;
```

Comment: I was doing that. But for some reason changing it to **android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat** didn't work. But manually typing **import....** worked. Thank you

Comment: @Sam. would you please answer this question?http://stackoverflow.com/q/41692300/3671748