# getting errors while using Notification.Builder

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am getting errors with these lines while handling notifications for different API levels. This is how i did so far:

```
...
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        Notification  notification;

if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

            notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, TaskDetails.class), 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        } 
        else
        {
            notification = new Notification.Builder(this) // error
             .setContentTitle(title) // in
             .setContentText(tmp_task_brief)  // these
             .setSmallIcon(icon) // lines
             .setLargeIcon(null) // telling "this method call requires API level 11
             .build(); // or higher"

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, TaskDetails.class), 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        }
...
```

I don't understand how to remove these errors. Please help me.

**Edit:** I did applied edit as below but NotificationCompact.Builer too got deprecated method `getNotification()` that returns Notification object.

```
if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
{
        notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
    } 
    else
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(icon)
        .setTicker(text)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text);

        notification = builder.getNotification();
        mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
    }
```

Comment: you try from
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717492/notifications-builder-in-api-10

Comment: @AnilMetatagg Yes. In this SO question, suggested to use `NotificationCompact.Builer` but it too has got deprecated method `getNotification()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NotificationCompact.Bulide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)r from support liberary (V4 liberary) that supports from 1.6

i think that will solves your problem.

Comment: I used this class but this class, too, got deprecated method `getNotification()` through which i can get `Notification` object.

Comment: At `developer.android.com` they suggested to use `build()` method, but i dont know how to use because build method takes no argument. I've no idea how to work with now.

Comment: getNotification is deprecated use build method but that was supported from api level 16. better ignore this class and use NotificationCompact.Builder if you want to support from api level 4

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. Voted up.

Comment: If you want demo please check this link i think this will helps you https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally, with the help of these guys i ended up to the solution of handling the deprecated methods:

```
if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

            notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    this);
            notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(text).setWhen(time)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text).build();

            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        }
```