# v4 support lib Notification not working

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-support-library

i found a weird behavior with android support library v4. Notification will work only if we set the set small icon for the notification else no notification will posted to on status bar. sample code is code is posted bellow please take look. Can anyone explain why this weird behavior.

```
 // below code will not post any notification 

 Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
 PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
 Notification n  = new Builder(context.getApplicationContext())
                 .setContentTitle("simple notification title")
                 .setContentText("simple message")
                 .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "More", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more",pIntent).build();
 NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                          notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

// below code will post notification

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
 PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
 Notification n  = new Builder(context.getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle("simple notification title")
                .setContentText("simple message")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
          //this below one line piece of code is making difference 
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "More", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more",pIntent).build();


 NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                          notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

Comment: I think you imported the correct .once Once you Check it...

Comment: You can have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16857267/1739882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html clearly states which notification content is required and which is optional.

a small icon is required.